# Windows 10 Photos app crashing on opening any image

Tags: windows, windows-10

When opening any image I'm getting this error:

[image: Error image]

I checked Event Viewer:

Event 1000:

```
Faulting application name: Microsoft.Photos.exe, version: 15.827.16340.0, time stamp: 0x55dfa48c
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16431, time stamp: 0x55c9bf27
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00000000005017ee
Faulting process id: 0xd3c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0ea04d37dd116
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_15.827.16340.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.Photos.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: ce64e369-c316-4871-b89b-65773f1a70a3
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.Photos_15.827.16340.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Event 5973:

```
Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

I tried running `sfc /scannow` and here is report (it didn't help)
This log is huge. But here are lines next to only line with "Error":

```
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    CheckSur: hrStatus: 0x800f081f [CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING], download Result: 0x800f0948 [CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING_FROM_WU_CAB]
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Count of times corruption detected: 1
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Seconds between initial corruption detections: -1
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Seconds between corruption and repair: -1
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Failed to run Detect and repair. [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Exec: Processing complete, session(Corruption Repairing): 30468613_3631800581 [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Error                 CBS    Session: 30468613_3631800581 failed to perform store corruption detect and repair operation. [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Session: 30468613_3631800581 finalized. Download error: 0x800f0948 [CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING_FROM_WU_CAB], Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
2015-09-08 09:21:25, Info                  CBS    Failed to FinalizeEx using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f081f]
```

I tried installing Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 10 and it didn't help.

I tried running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and it didn't work.

I tried running this in PowerShell with no success

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Comment: run **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth**: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 I treid that with no success. I even wrote it in my question.

Comment: look which files can't be repaired: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928228. Also generate a crash dump of crashing app. Download procdump (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx), store it in C:\dumps, run **procdump -ma -i C:\dumps** from a admin cmd. When the app crashes, go to C:\dumps, compress the dmp file as 7z/RAR, upload it to OneDrive, create a share link and post that link here.

Comment: have you created the dump? Can you see which files can't be repaired?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll do dumps in next 24 hours. I'm drowning I work I have to finish.